# Odoo 8 - Filter only the employees name in Calendar view instead of all the users(customers,users,employees)

Tags: filter, calendar, odoo-8

I would to filter only the employees in the Odoo8 calendar, by default it shows all the names(customers,users,employees). I want to show only the employee names.

Please help me to achieve this.

**The default view of the odoo calendar**
[image: Default view of odoo calendar]

**I want to remove the customer names form the drop down view. Only the employee names should be shown.**

[image: Default view of odoo calendar]

Answer (score 1):

You can create the field `many2one` to 'hr.employee' in file calendar.py.

Go to directory \addons\calendar\static\src\js\base_calendar.js after changing the file:

```js
initialize_m2o: function() {
        var self = this;
        this.dfm = new form_common.DefaultFieldManager(self);
        this.dfm.extend_field_desc({
            employee_id: {
                relation: "hr.employee",
            },
        });
        var FieldMany2One = core.form_widget_registry.get('many2one');
        this.ir_model_m2o = new FieldMany2One(self.dfm, {
            attrs: {
                class: 'o_add_favorite_calendar',
                name: "employee_id",
                type: "many2one",
                options: '{"no_open": True}',
                placeholder: _t("Add Favorite Calendar"),
            },
        });
        this.ir_model_m2o.appendTo(this.$el);
        this.ir_model_m2o.on('change:value', self, function() {
            // once selected, we reset the value to false.
            if (self.ir_model_m2o.get_value()) {
                self.add_filter();
            }
        });
    },
```

I should only show the employee list.

P.S. I use Odoo 9.